# Boot2Docker on Windows8 won't start due to "not finding ip for eth1"

Tags: windows, ip, virtualbox, boot2docker

when I try to start my freshly installed boot2docker 1.5 (got aware of the 1.6-bug) on windows8 there's the message, "no ip found for eth1".
I tried to re-install VirtualBox, but still the same message.

Even if I empty the HostOnly-Card of which the MAC matches the message loading boot2docker - without or with reinstalling the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a previous usecase for which I had VirtualBox installed before. All the config-data isn't deleted during uninstall. So I suppose it was that old xml-config containing some networking-details that were re-imposed on each new install-process.

After deleting everything being in folders containing "VirtualBox" everything got really re-installed and configured anew and boot2docker worked like a breeze.